# How to apply flatmap on JSONArray and convert to JSONObject in Spark?

Tags: java, arrays, apache-spark

I am working on spark java module, where I make a geocode api (batch request of 100 records). Now for every request I will get JSONArray of JSONObject in one row like as below.

Usually there will be 100 Address, but i gave only 2 addresses

```
  Locations        | Batch_Address
------------------------------------------
Address1,Address2  | [ { name:Address1,lat:12.89,lng:23.56} , { name:Address2,lat:12.3,lng:23.4} ]
```

What I required is like result as below

```
Address
----------
{ name:Address1,lat:12.89,lng:23.56}
{ name:Address2,lat:12.3,lng:23.4}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your code deals with java8, which has `java.util.Spliterator<T>` , so you can use it to create list from jsonarray.

**String type**

```
JavaRDD<String> JsonObject = json_Batch.javaRDD().flatMap(f -> {
            String res = f.getAs("Batch_Address").toString();


             JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray(res);


            List<String> list = StreamSupport.stream(jsonArr.spliterator(), false)
                    .map(val ->   val.toString())

                    .collect(Collectors.toCollection( ArrayList::new ));

            return list.iterator();

        }); 

        JsonObject.foreach(f -> System.out.println(f));
```

**JSONObject type**

```
  JavaRDD<JSONObject> JsonObject = json_Batch.javaRDD().flatMap(f -> {
            String res = f.getAs("Batch_Address").toString();


             JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray(res);


            List<JSONObject> list = StreamSupport.stream(jsonArr.spliterator(), false)
                    .map(val ->  (JSONObject) val)

                    .collect(Collectors.toCollection( ArrayList::new ));

            return list.iterator();

        }); 

        JsonObject.foreach(f -> System.out.println(f));
```